# Android Studio - How to use getExternalFilesDir

Tags: android, external

Since google killed the perfectly fine method getExternalStoragePublicDirectory, I have to try to get getExternalFilesDir to work.

This is one of the things I've tried:

```
private Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
private static final String test = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

error message:

```
Non-static field 'context' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I am not allowed to make context a static field though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is `this` reference to your activity, if yes then use:

```
this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I add a file name like "test.txt"?

Comment: like you used in `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`. use `this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/test.txt";`

Comment: When I ```.toString()``` the method I get the path ```/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.experimenting/files/Download/test.txt```. That is not correct, it should not include the app folder.

Comment: make another question for it, I already answered your question. which solves your error