# Location of file saved to Android folder

Tags: java, android

I'm following along this thread, and calling saveFrames
[MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime() returns only first frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772547/mediametadataretriever-getframeattime-returns-only-first-frame)

He is saving in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/videos/frames/" . Which turns out to be "/storage/emulated/0" . When I click on device explorer and "/storage/emulated" it says "Permission denied". Is there a way to access this, or is there another place that I can store the data?

Update:
So here's how I solved it. I can cd to that /storage/emulated/0 using  adb shell. However I cannot write to it. I change the directory name to

```
String folder = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/frame/" ;
```

I can see all the files there. To retrieve the files and view them, I use
`adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.<app>/files/Pictures/frame`

Here are more detailed discussions on storage permissions:

[WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE when targeting Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221188/write-external-storage-when-targeting-android-10#)

[Android Studio - How to use getExternalFilesDir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100505/android-studio-how-to-use-getexternalfilesdir)

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

[requestLegacyExternalStorage is not working in Android 11 - API 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364476/requestlegacyexternalstorage-is-not-working-in-android-11-api-30)

https://www.dev2qa.com/android-read-write-external-storage-file-example/

Comment: `Which turns out to be "/storage/emulated/0"` No. That would become  `"/storage/emulated/0/videos/frames"`.

Comment: `When I click on device explorerand "/storage/emulated" ` I have no idea what you are doing but "/storage/emulated" indeed often is not accessable. Any news?

Comment: I'm new to Android development. Im looking for a directory to save a bunch of temporary files. Any suggestions?

Comment: `"/storage/emulated/0/videos/frames"` ?

Comment: I can "adb shell" to navigate to /storage/emulated/0. However any when I navigate to that directory, the permissions are drwxrwx--x . I cannot change it. Any directory I create has the same permission. So my app cannot write to it. I'm using Android 10 emulator. Is there a way to change the permissions, so my app write a file to it?

Comment: `Any directory I create has the same permission`. Where are you creating which directories and how?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Two ways: 
1. using the above code: File saveFolder=new File(folder); saveFolder.mkdirs(); //This throws an en exception that it cannot create the file. Folder is /storage/emulated/0/videos/frames/ filename
2. adb shell; cd /storage/emulated/0; mkdir video; chmod 777 video; ls -al;  # I see permissions as drwxrwx--x;

I'm trying to write some temp files, so that I can examine it.

Comment: Android version of used device? Next time put your code in your post.

Comment: version 10 using the emulator. thanks again.